# split String without delimiters

Tags: java, string, split, delimiter

My controller recieves this String "20120115Z" as a @RequestParam, representing a date.

I would like to transform it to this format: yyyy-MM-dd, so I would have a new string like this 2012-01-15.

As you can see, there's no delimiters, only the 'Z' always as the last character.

My approach was pretty obvious:

```
String data = 
strData.substring(0, 4) + "-" + 
strData.substring(4, 6) + "-" + 
strData.substring(6, 8);
```

And it works, but as you know these "magic numbers" are something to avoid. I also tried to use a a regular expression like "^[^\s]{4}[^\s]{2}[^\s]{2}Z$", but without success.

Any idea?

**UPDATE: Finally I've done it with Joda-Time DateTime class as @Brian Agnew suggested**

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYYMMdd'T'hhmm'Z'");
String strData = "20120115T0600Z";
DateTime dt = fmt.parseDateTime(strData);
```

printing method:

```
private static void printDateTime(DateTime dt) {
    int year = dt.getYear();
    int month = dt.getMonthOfYear();
    int day = dt.getDayOfMonth();
    int hour = dt.getHourOfDay();
    int minute = dt.getMinuteOfHour();
    int second = dt.getSecondOfMinute();
    int millis = dt.getMillisOfSecond();
    String zone = dt.getZone().toString();
    log.info("fecha: "
            + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ":" + millis
            + " " + zone + "\n");
}
```

Output

```
15/1/2012 6:0:0:0 UTC
```

Thanks everyone

Comment: If the choice is between magic numbers and the same numbers used in the curse of a regex, well...

Comment: Why you want to avoid those numbers? I mean if you use Regex also, you would need to use the length. So, there is no way out. And also. its better to go with substring.

Comment: Your approach is fine. Keep it simple and just use sub-string. If you're really concerned about the magic numbers then pull them out to constants, e.g. YEAR_LENGTH and the like. But if it was me I'd just put it in a named method and comment so it's clear.

Comment: Ok thank you guys, I was concerned because I have "minor violations" about magic numbers from sonar code analyzer, and I would like to learn the standard way to do this common task. substring() wins ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would perhaps use a Joda-Time [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Why ? It'll check the format, including valid values for hours/minutes/seconds, and give you back a suitable [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object which you can do what with (including reformat it using a similar approach).

You simply give it the format that you want to parse and it'll do all the rest. You have a date, so treat it as such.

Comment: Thanks Brian, probably your solution is the best way to go. Joda-Time seems to be nice, also gives a solution to typical problems from java Date and Calendar classes. 

But by now I don't want to use an extra library only for this task, so substring() wins.. maybe in the next project. Thanks!

Comment: I would really recommend not restricting use of other libraries. Joda is a near essential for correct intuitive date work. Apache Commons has a ton of useful stuff etc etc. These will save you a lot of work in the future.

Comment: you're right Brian,

I'm just waiting to have some time to learn how it works and it will be in my projects, for sure.